# how to match values from a list to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Well I have this Excel file. 
On `column H` I have these codes for seismological stations where each station has a coefficient (as in picture 2).

These are 2 different sheets in the same file.

What I want is to match values from picture 2 with each value in picture 1 (cannot do it manually because they are more than a hundred thousand rows).

I tried to use the lookup function but it returns the wrong values or N/A.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: can you show your lookup function code?

Comment: What is the output supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula must look like this:

```
=VLOOKUP (H2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$28,2,FALSE)
```

The syntax of VLOOKUP is:

`VLOOKUP( lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup] )`

where the arguments are:

- **lookup_value** -   The value that you want to look up.
- **table_array**  -   The data array or table, containing the search values in the left hand columns and the return values in another column.
- **col_index_num**    -   The column number, within the supplied table_array, that you want to return a value from.
- **[range_lookup]**   - Optional. Can be TRUE or FALSE. If TRUE it will use the closest match. if FALSE it will return the exact match and otherwise it returns an error.

Comment: Hello. I FINALLY managed to do it with lookup. My problem was that in the 2nd list I have had some spaces in the 1st column. It should have been ''EFP'' but i had ''EFP '' so it was returning some wrong values or no values at all. Thanks for your time though.